# SOAP Request Fails when parameter is supplied

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, asmx, fiddler

When i call my Soap ASMX service with the parameter orderid , it fails and says . Any ideas?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/xml; charset=utf-8.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

> public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
>       {
>
> ```
>     [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
>     [SoapDocumentMethod]
>
>     public Order MyLiteralMethod([XmlElement("MyOrderID")] string orderId)
>     {
>
>        //logic
>     }
> }
> ```

**FIDDLER REQUEST HEADER**

```
Host: localhost:49033
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 369
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/MyLiteralMethod"
```

**FIDDLER REQUEST BODY**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <MyLiteralMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <MyOrderID>sdasd</MyOrderID>
    </MyLiteralMethod>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**FURTHER FINDINGS**
I am able to call the service and pass parameter from other web debugging proxy tools[STORM]. I think this is specific to fiddler

**Problem Resolved**

Seems like a issue with fiddler .went into tools->options->https.. Removed decrypt HTTPs traffic.. Restarted fiddler. Then re added those options back again and restarted. I dont know if this process solved the problem but i am able to make request via fiddler.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for tip but unfortunately ill have to use that as per the current infrastructure and business requirement

Answer (score 27):

I just had the same problem with an old ASMX service (this has nothing to do with Fiddler). Solution:

You are calling your web service using the SOAP protocol. I'm guessing that the URL you use to call it is:

```
http://yourserver/service.asmx/methodOfService
```

However, this URL must be used when you do a simple GET or POST to your service (when using AJAX for instance).
When using SOAP, you must use this URL:

```
http://yourserver/service.asmx
```

No method name, because it is included in the SOAP body.

Comment: I've been fighting with this for hours. Thanks so much!

Comment: This was my solution.

Comment: You saved my day :) Thank you a million times! It was working in a VS generated client but not in postman because of this (my) mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magical that Fiddler's doing here. Your simplest approach is to capture a working request with Fiddler, then use the **Compare** feature to compare that to the non-working request that you issued from the Composer tab.

Did you remember to set the HTTP Verb to `POST`?

If you remove the space before the charset, is there a change? `Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8`

Comment: i havent got any working request in fiddler to compare to. I got the request working from other tool called STORM. That space didnt make any diffrence